# Terraform list requires additional square brackets

Tags: terraform

I have the following terraform code

```
data "newrelic_application" "app1" {
  name = "app1"
}
data "newrelic_application" "app2" {
  name = "app2"
}

locals {
  apps = [
    "${data.newrelic_application.app1.id}",
    "${data.newrelic_application.app2.id}"
  ]
}

resource "newrelic_alert_condition" "api-response-time-background" {
  policy_id       = "${newrelic_alert_policy.my-policy.id}"
  name            = "API Response Time Background"
  type            = "apm_app_metric"
  entities        = "${local.apps}"  # <<<< Referenced here
  metric          = "response_time_background"
  condition_scope = "application"

  term {
    duration      = 5
    operator      = "above"
    priority      = "critical"
    threshold     = "1"
    time_function = "all"
  }
}
```

I have tried to simplify it. You can see that I have some data that I pull from the new relic provider, then I create an array of apps, which I reference in newrelic_alert_condition - entities.

This throws the following error

```
Error: newrelic_alert_condition.api-response-time-background: apps:` should be a list
```

When I modify the resource so that entities is an array like so

```
 resource "newrelic_alert_condition" "api-response-time-background" {
  policy_id       = "${newrelic_alert_policy.my-policy.id}"
  name            = "API Response Time Background"
  type            = "apm_app_metric"
  entities        = ["${local.apps}"]  # <<<< Updated here
  metric          = "response_time_background"
  condition_scope = "application"

  term {
    duration      = 5
    operator      = "above"
    priority      = "critical"
    threshold     = "1"
    time_function = "all"
  }
}
```

This works. What I want to know is why it doesn't work without the square brackets as the `local` I am passing in should already be a list. Is there a way to ensure the local received is a list? Is this a quirk of terraform?

Comment: I was going to say this is just a quirk of Terraform, but I've gotten it to work with similar resources. Is this the entire error message? Also, what version of terraform and the new relic provider are you using?

Comment: Yes that is the entire message. Complains it's not a list. Terraform v0.11.10, provider.newrelic: version = "~> 1.2"